# Unit Test JPA Specification's content

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We have implemented filtering for a repository by using JPA's Specification as follows:

```
public Page<CustomerDTO> searchCustomers(SearchDto searchDto) {
var queryFilters = this.getQueryFitlers(searchDto);
var paginationAndSorting = this.getPaginationAndSorting(searchDto.getPageNumber(),
    searchDto.getPageSize());
return customerRepository.findAll(queryFilters, paginationAndSorting)
    .map(entity -> {
      CustomerDTO dto = new CustomerDTO();
      copyProperties(entity, dto);
      return dto;
    })
}
```

And here is the queryFilters() method which uses Specifications:

```
private Specification<Customer> getQueryFitlers(CustomerSearchSpecDTO filteringValues) {

Specification<Customer> specification = Specification.where(null);

if (isNotBlank(filteringValues.getLastname())) {
  specification = specification.and(CustomerRepository.hasLastname(filteringValues.getLastname()));
}

if (isNotBlank(filteringValues.getTaxId())) {
  specification = specification.and(CustomerRepository.hasTaxId(filteringValues.getTaxId()));
}

// several more fields with the same approach
return specification;
}
```

Since these query filters are optional depending upon if the searchField is empty or not, what we would like to do is verify that the specification contains the proper "filters".
For example, if the searchDto input contains only taxId not blank, then I want to check that the returned specification contains such a "filter / specification".

Note: grabbing a reference to the result of this.getQueryFilters() (which is the Specifications) is not a problem, we already achieved that.

Comment: As this is related to DB, You can achieve this using Integration test.

Comment: We would like to do both, unit tests and functional tests